# How to reset variables or declarations vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to thank everyone who gives answers on this site for the years of helpful information I've been able to derive from this forum. This is my first question ever posted:

Here is the issue: I wrote the following code in order to create a continuous calendar that my co-workers can fill out and refresh to the current day and beyond. After I finished the code seemed to work until I used a second code that references this sheet from another sheet. After breaking apart the first code I realized that simply deleting any cell in the referenced sheet causes the second code to freeze up. It will continually look for the sheet but never find it. I was able to create a workaround where the code copies and pastes on the refresh macro instead of deleting any cells. However I'm afraid that someone will delete a cell in the future and cause problems on my workbook.

Here is my question: Is there a code that resets variables or declaring of variables without having to close and open the workbook.

Things I've tried: Not using variables and referencing the sheet directly, trying the same code and circumstances on another workbook and computer. I tried not deleting Range B1 but even deleting any cell on sheet 1 without a vba causes code 2 to freeze up. It will reset when the workbook is saved, closed and opened again.

Code 1 on Sheet 1:

```
Sub OoDCalUpdate()
    '
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
    '

    Dim str As String

    str = Range("A2")

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    iFind = Range("B1:CF1").Find(str).Column

    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(100, iFind)).**Delete**

    Range(Cells(1, 85 - iFind), Cells(2, 85 - iFind)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 85 - iFind), Cells(2, 84)), Type:=xlFillSeries

    errHandler:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

In case you need Code 2 on Sheet 2 I put asterix where I believe the code freezes:

```
Sub CalendarMaker()

       ' Unprotect sheet if had previous calendar to prevent error.
       ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, _
          Scenarios:=False
       ' Prevent screen flashing while drawing calendar.
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       ' Set up error trapping.

       ' Clear area a1:g14 including any previous calendar.
       Range("A1:O27").Clear
       ' Use InputBox to get desired month and year and set variable
       ' MyInput.

       ' Allow user to end macro with Cancel in InputBox.

       **Dim ws As Worksheet
       Dim str As String

       Set ws = Worksheets("OoD Tracker")
       str = Worksheets("OoD Tracker").Range("B1")**



'MONTH 1

       ' Get the date value of the beginning of inputted month.
       StartDay = DateValue(str)
       ' Check if valid date but not the first of the month
       ' -- if so, reset StartDay to first day of month.
       If Day(StartDay) <> 1 Then
           StartDay = DateValue(Month(StartDay) & "/1/" & _
               Year(StartDay))
       End If
       ' Prepare cell for Month and Year as fully spelled out.
       Range("a1").NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"
       ' Center the Month and Year label across a1:g1 with appropriate
       ' size, height and bolding.
       With Range("a1:g1")
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           .Font.Size = 18
           .Font.Bold = True
           .RowHeight = 35
           .Interior.ColorIndex = 33
       End With
       ' Prepare a2:g2 for day of week labels with centering, size,
       ' height and bolding.
       With Range("a2:g2")
           .ColumnWidth = 15
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           .Orientation = xlHorizontal
           .Font.Size = 12
           .Font.Bold = True
           .RowHeight = 20
       End With
       ' Put days of week in a2:g2.
       Range("a2") = "Sunday"
       Range("b2") = "Monday"
       Range("c2") = "Tuesday"
       Range("d2") = "Wednesday"
       Range("e2") = "Thursday"
       Range("f2") = "Friday"
       Range("g2") = "Saturday"
       ' Prepare a3:g7 for dates with left/top alignment, size, height
       ' and bolding.
       With Range("a3:g8")
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
           .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
           .Font.Size = 18
           .Font.Bold = True
           .RowHeight = 21
       End With
       ' Put inputted month and year fully spelling out into "a1".
       Range("a1").Value = Application.Text(str, "mmmm yyyy")
       ' Set variable and get which day of the week the month starts.
       DayofWeek = Weekday(StartDay)
       ' Set variables to identify the year and month as separate
       ' variables.
       CurYear = Year(StartDay)
       CurMonth = Month(StartDay)
       ' Set variable and calculate the first day of the next month.
       FinalDay = DateSerial(CurYear, CurMonth + 1, 1)
       ' Place a "1" in cell position of the first day of the chosen
       ' month based on DayofWeek.
       Select Case DayofWeek
           Case 1
               Range("a3").Value = 1
           Case 2
               Range("b3").Value = 1
           Case 3
               Range("c3").Value = 1
           Case 4
               Range("d3").Value = 1
           Case 5
               Range("e3").Value = 1
           Case 6
               Range("f3").Value = 1
           Case 7
               Range("g3").Value = 1
       End Select
       ' Loop through range a3:g8 incrementing each cell after the "1"
       ' cell.
       For Each cell In Range("a3:g8")
           RowCell = cell.Row
           ColCell = cell.Column
           ' Do if "1" is in first column.
           If cell.Column = 1 And cell.Row = 3 Then
           ' Do if current cell is not in 1st column.
           ElseIf cell.Column <> 1 Then
               If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value >= 1 Then
                   cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
                   ' Stop when the last day of the month has been
                   ' entered.
                   If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                       cell.Value = ""
                       ' Exit loop when calendar has correct number of
                       ' days shown.
                       Exit For
                   End If
               End If
           ' Do only if current cell is not in Row 3 and is in Column 1.
           ElseIf cell.Row > 3 And cell.Column = 1 Then
               cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 6).Value + 1
               ' Stop when the last day of the month has been entered.
               If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                   cell.Value = ""
                   ' Exit loop when calendar has correct number of days
                   ' shown.
                   Exit For
               End If
           End If
       Next


'MONTH 2

       ' Get the date value of the beginning of inputted month.
       StartDay = DateValue(str)
       ' Check if valid date but not the first of the month
       ' -- if so, reset StartDay to first day of month.
       If Day(StartDay) <> 1 Then
           StartDay = DateValue(Month(StartDay) + 1 & "/1/" & _
               Year(StartDay))
       End If
       ' Prepare cell for Month and Year as fully spelled out.
       Range("I1").NumberFormat = "mmmm yyyy"
       ' Center the Month and Year label across I1:O1 with appropriate
       ' size, height and bolding.
       With Range("I1:O1")
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           .Font.Size = 18
           .Font.Bold = True
           .RowHeight = 35
           .Interior.ColorIndex = 22
       End With
       ' Prepare I2:O2 for day of week labels with centering, size,
       ' height and bolding.
       With Range("I2:O2")
           .ColumnWidth = 15
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
           .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
           .Orientation = xlHorizontal
           .Font.Size = 12
           .Font.Bold = True
           .RowHeight = 20
       End With
       ' Put days of week in I2:O2.
       Range("I2") = "Sunday"
       Range("J2") = "Monday"
       Range("K2") = "Tuesday"
       Range("L2") = "Wednesday"
       Range("M2") = "Thursday"
       Range("N2") = "Friday"
       Range("O2") = "Saturday"
       ' Prepare I3:O7 for dates with left/top alignment, size, height
       ' and bolding.
       With Range("I3:O8")
           .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
           .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
           .Font.Size = 18
           .Font.Bold = True
           .RowHeight = 21
       End With
       ' Put inputted month and year fully spelling out into "I1".
       Range("I1").Value = Application.Text(StartDay, "mmmm yyyy")
       ' Set variable and get which day of the week the month starts.
       DayofWeek = Weekday(StartDay)
       ' Set variables to identify the year and month as separate
       ' variables.
       CurYear = Year(StartDay)
       CurMonth = Month(StartDay)
       ' Set variable and calculate the first day of the next month.
       FinalDay = DateSerial(CurYear, CurMonth + 1, 1)
       ' Place a "1" in cell position of the first day of the chosen
       ' month based on DayofWeek.
       Select Case DayofWeek
           Case 1
               Range("I3").Value = 1
           Case 2
               Range("J3").Value = 1
           Case 3
               Range("K3").Value = 1
           Case 4
               Range("L3").Value = 1
           Case 5
               Range("M3").Value = 1
           Case 6
               Range("N3").Value = 1
           Case 7
               Range("O3").Value = 1
       End Select
       ' Loop through range I3:O8 incrementing each cell after the "1"
       ' cell.
       For Each cell In Range("I3:O8")
           RowCell = cell.Row
           ColCell = cell.Column
           ' Do if "1" is in first column.
           If cell.Column = 9 And cell.Row = 3 Then
           ' Do if current cell is not in 1st column.
           ElseIf cell.Column <> 9 Then
               If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value >= 1 Then
                   cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value + 1
                   ' Stop when the last day of the month has been
                   ' entered.
                   If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                       cell.Value = ""
                       ' Exit loop when calendar has correct number of
                       ' days shown.
                       Exit For
                   End If
               End If
           ' Do only if current cell is not in Row 3 and is in Column 9.
           ElseIf cell.Row > 3 And cell.Column = 9 Then
               cell.Value = cell.Offset(-1, 6).Value + 1
               ' Stop when the last day of the month has been entered.
               If cell.Value > (FinalDay - StartDay) Then
                   cell.Value = ""
                   ' Exit loop when calendar has correct number of days
                   ' shown.
                   Exit For
               End If
           End If
       Next

       ' Create Entry cells, format them centered, wrap text, and border
       ' around days.
       For x = 0 To 5
           Range("I4").Offset(x * 2, 0).EntireRow.Insert
           With Range("I4:O4").Offset(x * 2, 0)
               .RowHeight = 65
               .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
               .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
               .WrapText = True
               .Font.Size = 12
               .Font.Bold = False
               ' Unlock these cells to be able to enter text later after
               ' sheet is protected.
               .Locked = False
           End With
           ' Put border around the block of dates.
           With Range("I3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
           7).Borders(xlLeft)
               .Weight = xlThick
               .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           End With

           With Range("I3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
           7).Borders(xlRight)
               .Weight = xlThick
               .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           End With
           Range("I3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, 7).BorderAround _
              Weight:=xlThick, ColorIndex:=xlAutomatic
       Next
       If Range("I13").Value = "" Then Range("I13:O13").Offset(0, 0) _
          .Resize(2, 8).Delete

'REST OF MONTH 1

       ' Create Entry cells, format them centered, wrap text, and border
       ' around days.
       For x = 0 To 5

           With Range("A4:G4").Offset(x * 2, 0)
               .RowHeight = 65
               .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
               .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
               .WrapText = True
               .Font.Size = 12
               .Font.Bold = False
               ' Unlock these cells to be able to enter text later after
               ' sheet is protected.
               .Locked = False
           End With
           ' Put border around the block of dates.
           With Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
           7).Borders(xlLeft)
               .Weight = xlThick
               .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           End With

           With Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, _
           7).Borders(xlRight)
               .Weight = xlThick
               .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
           End With
           Range("A3").Offset(x * 2, 0).Resize(2, 7).BorderAround _
              Weight:=xlThick, ColorIndex:=xlAutomatic
       Next
       If Range("A13").Value = "" Then Range("A13:G13").Offset(0, 0) _
          .Resize(2, 8).Delete


       Dim strMo As String
       Dim MoRow As Integer
       Dim MoCol As Integer
       Dim DaRow As Integer
       Dim DaCol As Integer

        With Application.FindFormat.Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        End With
       For Counter = 2 To 84
       tcell = ws.Cells(1, Counter)
       strMo = DateValue(Month(tcell) & "/1/" & Year(tcell))
       strDa = Format(tcell, "d")
       MoRow = Range("A1:O30").Find(strMo, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True).Row
       MoCol = Range("A1:O30").Find(strMo, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True).Column
       DaRow = Range(Cells(MoRow, MoCol), Cells(MoRow + 14, MoCol + 6)).Find(strDa, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True).Row
       DaCol = Range(Cells(MoRow, MoCol), Cells(MoRow + 14, MoCol + 6)).Find(strDa, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchFormat:=True).Column
       Cells(DaRow + 1, DaCol).Value = "='OoD Tracker'!" & ws.Cells(2, Counter).Address
       Next Counter

       ' Turn off gridlines.
       ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
       ' Protect sheet to prevent overwriting the dates.
       ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, _
          Scenarios:=True

       ' Resize window to show all of calendar (may have to be adjusted
       ' for video configuration).
       ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
       ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

       ' Allow screen to redraw with calendar showing.
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       ' Prevent going to error trap unless error found by exiting Sub
       ' here.
       Exit Sub
   ' Error causes msgbox to indicate the problem, provides new input box,
   ' and resumes at the line that caused the error.
MyErrorTrap:
       MsgBox "Please check OoD Tracker sheet to ensure the dates are correct. See LitProd Data Help File for more information."
       Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're asking but here's a few things. You can `ReDim` a variable, `set variable = nothing` or just leave it. VBA clears the variables when the macro finishes executing so you don't need to tidy up like in some other languages

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I couldn't figure out how to use ReDim in my code but I tried set ws = nothing and str = a different range before set them correctly and it didn't have an effect. That's what I thought VBA is supposed to do after executing, but it seems like Code 2 freezes when any cell is deleted from the Sheet it is referencing.

Comment: comment out `On Error GoTo errHandler` and run it again to see the errors. If you do `On Error GoTo errHandler` and any error occurs you don't see it and the sub ends without any message. Also try to debug your code step by step using F8

Comment: `Redim` is only issued to change the size of an array already declared. Do you have any event code?

Comment: Thank you Peh and SJR for your suggestions. You helped give me new troubleshooting ideas. To your answer Peh: The Code that freezes is Code 2 instead of Code 1 and I have my error trap off. Debugging with F8 helped confirm that the Code 2 stops right before I Dim my variables and gives me no error, it simply stops and starts over. This happens after I delete a cell from Sheet 1 this problem occurs on Code 2. Thank you for the suggestion but I have yet to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: To your answer SJR: That was a great idea, since I did have an event code on Sheet 1, however getting rid of my event code did not help. I did however find that when I Cleared Formats from Sheet 1 and then deleted cells from Sheet 1 I had no problems in Code 2. I still haven't pinpointed why Code 2 freezes when I delete a cell on Sheet 1 (the sheet that it references) when Sheet 1 has certain formats on it. All I have on Sheet 1 is a continuous Line along all columns and some Date formats. It seems like if I have Lines on each column and a line on the first column it causes the freeze